# Div hover not working when scrolling in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover

Please take a look at this code: http://jsfiddle.net/6JnJb/1/
My problem is that in chrome, the divs doesn't change their color if the mouse is over them, when scrolling. If I move the mouse over a div 'manually' (not when scrolling) than it changes it's color to red.
In Firefox it works perfect, but not in Chrome.
Can I solve this problem or simply this how Chrome works?

Comment: What version of chrome are you using? It works for me in 16.0.912.75 m

Comment: Exactly your version. When you just 'scroll over the divs', they change their colors?

Comment: Yeah, even [changed the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6JnJb/2/) to make sure the divs were different ones. A silly question, but are you sure you are not hitting the space between the divs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chrome does not propagate mouseover events right away when scrolling. There really isn't any way around this issue, since it is giving priority to the scrolling event rather than the hover event on a particular element.

The behavior I see is that the hover effect doesn't move with the still mouse on scroll but catches up when the scroll speed is sufficiently low.

Comment: I would assume that Chrome would update `:hover` at least after scrolling is done. This looks like it might be bug :o

Firefox is also ignoring when scrolling but after scroll ended it updates properly.

Comment: No mouse over updates while scrolling was a feature added in Chrome 45 https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5697181675683840