# CSS hover doesn't trigger until scroll stops or mouse moves

Tags: css, scroll, hover

Why does my css`:hover` effect not start until the scroll animation completes / my cursor moves? Is there any way I can make the`:hover` event trigger on immediate mouseOver?

https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/mdxNReL

Comment: No mouse over updates while scrolling was a feature added in Chrome 45 chromestatus.com/feature/5697181675683840

Comment: Is there no way to force update?

Answer (score 0):

As chrome prioritises scrolling, hover will work after the scroll is over. So there is no solution for it as of now. A similar question has been asked previously which you can refer below.

[div-hover-not-working-when-scrolling-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927179/div-hover-not-working-when-scrolling-in-chrome)