# ToolTip does not disappear on scroll

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tooltip

I have a button on the site and a ToolTip to it, which describes the action of the button.

But there is one bug that I can not solve (and I'm already starting to doubt if there is a solution to this problem).

Description of the problem: when the user hovers over the icon, a tooltip appears - everything works fine here. But if at this moment the table is scrolling, then the tooltip flies out of bounds. It's hard to describe, take a look

Pay attention to how the tooltip (if the cursor is hovered over) flies up or down when scrolling.

Tell me how to solve this problem?

```
          <div>
            <Tooltip 
              title="Delete" 
              arrow
              componentsProps={{
                tooltip: {
                    sx: {
                        bgcolor: '#a3a3a3',
                        '& .MuiTooltip-arrow': {
                            color: '#a3a3a3',
                        },
                    },
                  },
                }}
                PopperProps={{
                    modifiers: [
                        {
                            name: "offset",
                            options: {
                                offset: [0, -8],
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                }}>
              <DeleteForeverIcon/>
            </Tooltip>
          </div>
```

Instruction: hover over any cell from the first column, wait for the tooltip to appear. Then scroll the wheel up or down and see how the tooltip goes outside the table

P.s. Please note that this question has already been answered. And in principle this solution is working. But I had a lot of problems when adding this solution to my real code. Probably a simple solution for me here would be to simply cancel the scrolling when you hover over the button. Tell me how this can be done (but keep in mind that position: fixed is not suitable in this case)

Comment: Try changing `z-index`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Tell me more specifically where and how should I do it

Comment: Which tooltip package are you using ? react-tooltip or mui tooltip? any npm repo link?

Comment: @PallamollaSai I use this tooltip https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is different, where each tooltip maintains its own state. It is using `IntersectionObserver` to determine if the `ToolTip` component is viewable. When the component is no longer viewable, it will hide the `Popper` (the tooltip popup) by setting the CSS to `display: 'none'` via the `sx` prop on `PopperProps`.

Codesandbox Example: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-fix-2sv5p4?file=/src/FileDownloadButton.jsx:0-1473)

Here is the modified file `FileDownloadButton.jsx`:

```js
import React from "react";
import FileDownloadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileDownload";
import { ButtonGroup, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";

export default function FileDownloadButton() {
  const tipRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [inView, setInView] = React.useState(false);

  const cb = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    entry.isIntersecting ? setInView(true) : setInView(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px"
    };
    const ref = tipRef.current;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(cb, options);

    if (ref) observer.observe(ref);

    return () => {
      if (ref) observer.unobserve(ref);
    };
  }, [tipRef]);

  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      <div>
        <Tooltip
          ref={tipRef}
          title="Download record "
          arrow
          componentsProps={{
            tooltip: {
              sx: {
                bgcolor: "#a3a3a3",
                "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
                  color: "#a3a3a3"
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          PopperProps={{
            sx: { display: inView ? "block" : "none" },
            modifiers: [
              {
                name: "offset",
                options: {
                  offset: [0, -8]
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        >
          <FileDownloadIcon />
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

---

## Changes for reference

### Change 1

```js
export default function FileDownloadButton() {
  const tipRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [inView, setInView] = React.useState(false);

  const cb = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    entry.isIntersecting ? setInView(true) : setInView(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px"
    };
    const ref = tipRef.current;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(cb, options);

    if (ref) observer.observe(ref);

    return () => {
      if (ref) observer.unobserve(ref);
    };
  }, [tipRef]);
```

### Change 2

```js
PopperProps={{
    sx: { display: inView ? "block" : "none" },
```

---

### Update 1

#### Original poster wants toggle

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-tooltip-toggle-nsv773?file=/src/FileDownloadButton.jsx:0-1803)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FileDownloadIcon from "@mui/icons-material/FileDownload";
import { ButtonGroup, IconButton, Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import VisibilityOffIcon from "@mui/icons-material/VisibilityOff";
import VisibilityIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Visibility";

export default function FileDownloadButton() {
  const [click, setClick] = useState(true);

  const tipRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [inView, setInView] = React.useState(false);

  const cb = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    entry.isIntersecting ? setInView(true) : setInView(false);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px"
    };
    const ref = tipRef.current;
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(cb, options);

    if (ref) observer.observe(ref);

    return () => {
      if (ref) observer.unobserve(ref);
    };
  }, [tipRef]);

  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      <div>
        <Tooltip
          ref={tipRef}
          title={click ? "Show item" : "Hide Item"}
          arrow
          componentsProps={{
            tooltip: {
              sx: {
                bgcolor: "#a3a3a3",
                "& .MuiTooltip-arrow": {
                  color: "#a3a3a3"
                }
              }
            }
          }}
          PopperProps={{
            sx: { display: inView ? "block" : "none" },
            modifiers: [
              {
                name: "offset",
                options: {
                  offset: [0, -8]
                }
              }
            ]
          }}
        >
          <IconButton onClick={() => setClick(!click)}>
            {click ? <VisibilityOffIcon /> : <VisibilityIcon />}
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

Comment: @vl1qu1d Thank you for paying attention to my question. This is just a great solution, I thank you!!! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad I could help! You're also my first bounty question :D. Happy coding!!!

Comment: @1qu1d I'm sorry to bother you, maybe you can help. At the moment, the tooltip disappears when it goes beyond the boundaries of the table, but is it possible to make it so that the tooltip disappears immediately when scrolling starts

Comment: It is, but you're going to have to rework the code to blend Pallamolla Sai's solution into my solution. I don't recommend this approach as you'll be cutting off the tooltip animation immediately. Honestly, if you're wanting this type of feature, you should create a feature request on MUI's github, because the way the tooltip works now was the intended goal.

Comment: @Paul Please check the updated answer. While you mean well, please understand that saying the code has "a small bug" when it does not (because of the scope change to the original question) is offensive. 

I take great pride and time in the code I write, including here on Stackoverflow. Additionally, you should take care when copying code found on this site without understanding the underlying fundamentals of it. While the code I wrote is efficient, there could be other solutions that cause things to become slow.

Comment: I apologize if I offended you in any way. I really didn't want this. (perhaps these are translation difficulties, since sometimes I use Google translate. And in the future I will be attentive). On the contrary, I am very grateful and grateful for your help. P.s. The changes you made are working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is browser specific issue. When I checked the given url( https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-grass-1lb3qw) in firefox browser it was working fine(but not in the chrome). Later figured that out hover while scrolling on element will work differently in the chrome compare to other browsers since latest versions.

I made following changes to make it work in chrome. Basically whenever we hover any item then the material tooltip is being added to the document. So what I did was I have attached an scroll event and if there is any material tooltip element is present I just simply removed it.

DeviceTable.jsx

```
export default function DevicesTable() {
  const tableRef = useRef();

  function removeElementsByClass(className){
     const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
     while(elements.length > 0){
       elements[0].remove();
     }

  }

  useEffect(() => {
     if (tableRef.current) {
       tableRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
          // CLASS NAME OF THE TOOLTIP ATTACHED TO THE DOM. THERE ARE MULTIPLE CLASSES BUT I FOUND FOLLOWING CLASSNAME TO BE UNIQUE. PLEASE CROSS CHECK FROM YOUR END AS WELL.
          //YOU CAN CHECK THIS BY PASSING open={true} attribute on <Tooltip> AND INSPECT DOM
         removeElementsByClass("css-yk351k-MuiTooltip-tooltip")
       });
     }
     return () => {
       if(tableRef.current) {
          tableRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", ()=>{});
       }
     }
  }, []);

return (
  <TableContainer  className="TableContainerGridStyle">
    <Table className="TableStyle">
      <DevicesTableHeader />
      // CHANGED LINE
      <TableBody ref={tableRef} className="TableBodyStyle">
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        <DevicesTableCell />
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
  </TableContainer>
 );
}
```

Apart from the above I think you can use another alternatives like followCursor, setting the position relative attribute to the table cell(TableCellStyle) or body. But these don't solve the problem fully.

As you are passing Table component as props children to the StateLabel component so in order to display/render we need to update StateLabel component to use props.children

```
export default function StateLabel({children}) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

[Div hover not working when scrolling in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927179/div-hover-not-working-when-scrolling-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to my question.
First of all, I am very grateful for your help.
Secondly, I tried your method, yes, it works. Great!
And thirdly, I would like to clarify one point. I added in codeSandbox a very simplified and very abbreviated version of my real version (to make it easier for people to understand), but I didn't think it would lead to an error.

Comment: The error is as follows: I have a StateLabel component (I already added it to the code-sandbox). And with this component, the application completely crashes with an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). There is nothing complicated about this component, but nevertheless the error appears.

Comment: In the StateLabel you are passing Table as children. But you are not rendering that in the the StateLabel component which in result it doesn't rendering/displaying the Table component. So in order to render Table component I have used props.children in the StateLabel component. I have edited the answer please check it once.